# Anonymous must have edit permissions, however in this case they can edit some poll's data

Tags: drupal, permissions, module

as far as I know, anonymous users have to have 'edit any poll content' permission in order to be able to vote. But this causes that they have access to editing some of the poll's data on particular url (www.myweb.com/node/numberofnode/edit).
How can I restrict this access? 
I haven't found anything about this on drupal's forum which surprises me.
Thanks

edit:Drupal version 6.19

Answer (score 2):

This sounds wrong, the permission "vote on polls" should be enough to allow anon users to vote on polls.

"edit any poll content" is exactly that, *editing* them.

Where did you get that information from?

Comment: In my Drupal version (6.19) there is no such choice of 'vote on polls'. There are just choices 'create poll','delete any poll','delete own poll','edit any poll content','edit own poll content'

Comment: The you have a different Drupal than I do. See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--poll--poll.module/function/poll_perm/6 for the existing permissions.